# Would not it be safe if I saved the Access Token to the client

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

In authorization code flow，we can see the access token get by the client（the client is client server）.After Authorization，the server store the access token in session not in client.So when I want to request the resource server, whether to request the client server to obtain Access Token, and then request the resource server.Would not it be safe if I saved the Access Token to the client?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9mQr.png)

Comment: Is it a coding problem?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, you want to get an access token from your backend to your frontend (JavaScript) and then use it for calling a resource server using XHR? Why do you want to have it on both the backend and the frontend?